# Will 14.4 volts from my solar charge controller damage my 12v equipment?

Tags: buck, solar-energy, lead-acid, solar-charge-controller, fluid-pump

My charge controller is set to recharge my battery bank and begin a float charge at 14.4 volts.
If I use some of my 12 volt components during the day while the batteries are charging, will this high voltage damage my diaphragm pumps and Arduino etc.?

I thought of adjusting the float charge level at the controller but someone told me that doing so will be bad for my sealed lead acid batteries.

I'm thinking of using XL4015 or XL4016 buck converters, but I want to maximize the power before reaching the 11.1V load disconnect..

And advice and correction will be highly appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What do the manuals of your 12V equipment say? We don't have a list of equipment you have and it would be huge effort to find out service manuals or reverse engineer the schematics for each of them to estimate whether they tolerate 14.4V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really does depend on the "12V" equipment.

If it's designed for automotive use, or motorhome/RV or marine use, it'll be designed with car batteries in mind, and generally tolerant of 15V or so while the battery's charging - as well as the sort of voltage spikes sometimes seen in a car.

Plus, DC motors used in pumps and such are pretty robust anyway.

If it was designed with a precision regulated 12V supply in mind ... maybe not.

Arduino should have a step-down regulator to 5V in the system so it should be fine (but if it's a linear regulator, it may get hotter and need a bigger heatsink)

So add a list of the specific equipment you have in mind, to the question, and hopefully you'll get a better answer. If some specific item is NOT so robust, a regulated supply should take care of that, leaving everything else on the battery.

Comment: Thanks to you answer now I'm not so worried anymore. God bless you